# How to smoothen up the boot process in Elementary juno

Tags: boot

My system boots within 20 seconds which I guess is normal ?

At boot, there is a command-line login screen that is visible for a small fraction of a second..is this normal too ? is there a way to remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the command screen too, it's normal. I would not mind it too much.

And your boot time is pretty good, I have around 50 seconds on a Dell XPS 9550.

Comment: 50 seconds from button press to desktop or from after dell logo to desktop ?

Comment: In my case, it takes 40 seconds from button press to desktop and 27 seconds from Dell logo to desktop...

Comment: 50 from button press to user login/desktop.

Comment: That aint that bad...maybe reorder the boot sequence..turn off fast boot or secure boot...My laptop has a SATA3 SSD with an intel core m processor ..I also wondered why it is so high...eOS is like that...I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop which has an i7-7700HQ + PCIe SSD...with that I used to get sub 10s boot times...

Comment: I still had around 40 seconds with Ubuntu 18.10, so I'm not too bothered. I believed Fast Boot in BIOS was supposed to makes things faster, no? Why turning it off?